# setup Gitlab CI

Tags: server, ssh, gitlab

I have setup Gitlab in ubuntu server, it's working fine. I access Gitlab by url `http://123.456.789.100` and Gitlab login details

```
username:admin@local.host 
password:123456
```

Then I wanted to set Gitlab CI for test the code before it merge. I have done with setting Gitlab CI by using the [link](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/installation.md). I have done setting up every thing except Runners. While set `ssh git@<your gitlab url>` in Runner I face error

```
ssh git@123.456.789.100
```

it prompts me for password

```
git@123.456.789.100's password:
```

I entered password(123456) of gitlab's that I used to enter into gitlab server, then I have this error

```
Permission denied please try again
```

But I got Gitlab CI web interface by `http://123.456.789.100:8081`(I did set Gitlab-ci to listen on 8081 port). Then I entered Gitlab server's username and password as admin@local.host and 123456, I got Invalid credentials.

What would be the wrong I made?

---

I am able to login gitlab_ci by gitlab's username and password. All I need to do is add url of gitlab server in /home/gitlab_ci/config/application.yml file and select that gitlab server's url in Gitlab_ci WebUI.

but I still getting error while do `ssh git@123.456.789.100` on Gitlab_CI Runner

Answer (score 0):

You have to ssh with an ubuntu user account, gitlab_ci and gitlab user account are independent of the os user accounts although some people may use the same password for both accounts.